# How does Tkinter get window destruction events instead of mainloop quit

Tags: python, tkinter

I have extended Tkinter's mainloop function so that Tkinter's main loop can constantly refresh the interface in while true. And I can add other loop events in while true, such as socket listening or schedule task, but I don't know when to break the while true loop. I think we should capture the window destruction event to judge whether to end the process.

```py
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.center((600, 460))


    def center(self, size: Tuple[int, int] = None):
        w, h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        x, y = int((w - size[0]) / 2), int((h - size[1]) / 2)
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}+{x}+{y}")

    def mainloop(self, n: float = ...) -> None:
        """
        N main cycle timeout exit seconds if 0, do not use the main cycle
        """
        if n == 0:
            self.update()
        else:
            self.after(n * 1000, self.quit)
            super().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Window("app")
    while True:
         print(time.time())
         app.mainloop(1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have. Using Tkinter protocol, you can call back a closing function. It will set the existence status of the window to false, and then judge in recycling to exit

```py
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self, title: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.center((600, 460))
        self._active = True
        self.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.close)

    def close(self):
        self._active = False
        self.quit()

    def center(self, size: Tuple[int, int] = None):
        w, h = self.winfo_screenwidth(), self.winfo_screenheight()
        x, y = int((w - size[0]) / 2), int((h - size[1]) / 2)
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}+{x}+{y}")

    def mainloop(self, n: int = ...) -> bool:
        if n == 0:
            self.update()
        else:
            self.after(n * 1000, self.quit)
            super().mainloop()
        return self._active


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Window("app")
    while True:
        print(time.time())
        if not app.mainloop(1):
            break
```